# sql Use Fieldvalue in sql subquery

Tags: sql, subquery

I need a little bit of help with a subquery inside a storedproc.

I have two tables

```
Tab1: @WerteTab (WVaNr, WVaBez, WVaVon, WVaBis, WVaOrt)

Tab2: TemplateTab(TempField, ViewField)
```

Values of TemplateTab are

```
Counter TempField  ViewField
1       ccVABez    WVaBez
2       ccVAVon    WVaVon
3       ccVaBis    WVaBis
```

My SQL looks like

```
SELECT 
    TemplateTab.TempField, 
    (Select TemplateTab.ViewField From @WerteTab) AS Feldwert
FROM 
    TemplateTab
```

@WerteTab has just one row

So, the value of `TemplateTab.ViewField` is the `columnName` of `Tab1`

When I run the SQL `Feldwert` has the same values like `ViewField`

When I replace `TemplateTab.ViewField` with `WVaBez` I get the right value from `Tab1`

Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  tt.TempField
,       case ViewField
        when 'WVaNr' then wt.WVaNr
        when 'WVaBez' then wt.WVaBez
        when 'WVaVon' then wt.WVaVon
        when 'WVaBis' then wt.WVaBis
        when 'WVaOrt' then wt.WVaOrt
        end as Feldwert
FROM    TemplateTab tt
CROSS JOIN
        @WerteTab wt
```

Comment: You could just do a CROSS JOIN to make the THENs a little simpler

Comment: @ConradFrix: Good point, I guess we can assume it's SQL Server because of the `@WerteTab` table variable